# JavaScript; How do I declare a variable global?

Tags: javascript, jquery, declaration

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/6kvyb/

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>

<script>
$('li').each(function(index) {
    var qq=$(this).text();
    alert(index + ': ' + qq);
  });


alert(qq);// Asking this one.
</script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've declared qq inside the scope of the function. Once that function exits, qq doesn't exist anymore.

If you want to have an alert for qq, you need to declare it outside of the function. Keep in mind that it will only contain the last value that was assigned to it.

```
var qq;

$('li').each(function(index) {
    qq=$(this).text();
    alert(index + ': ' + qq);
  });

alert(qq); // Will alert 'bar'
```

Comment: What can I do to carry out of the function? In PHP I can use global to use it out of the function but in JS I don't know.

Comment: @borayeris The code in this answer "globals" the variable, making it work. :)

Comment: @borayeris: you "could" by skipping the `var`. That would explicitly push `qq` into the global (`window`) object. Anyway, it's pretty bad karma to put anything like this into the global namespace, don't do it.

Comment: @borayeris, bzlm is correct. The code will allow you to alert the last value of qq. If you want to store a list of all the values of qq, you can use an array.

Comment: I know how to do it. I just needed to learn how to make a variable (or array) global. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Brandon's answer is correct in explaining why.  If, instead, you want to know how you could make it accessible after the call to each(), you probably want something like this:

```
var qq;

$('li').each(function(index) {
    qq = $(this).text();

    alert(index + ': ' + qq);
  });


alert(qq);
```

This makes qq a global scope variable, which you're reassigning the value of for each pass through the loop.  At the end of the loop the variable will retain the last value assigned to it (bar in your example).

Answer (score 0):

It should be rewritten like this:

```
<script>
var qq;
$('li').each(function(index) {
qq=$(this).text();
alert(index + ': ' + qq);
});
alert(qq);
```

;

Note that qq will only contain the last value since you reassign it each time you loop through the li.

It was not working because you declared the qq variable inside an anonymous function, so it did not exist outside of it.